# Shell script could run with absolute path, but error with relative path

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

Environment：Centos6 64bit

There's a shell script (named `mysql.sh`); it's located in file: `/home/user1/sbin/mysql.sh`

While running this script with parameter 'restart', its outcomes are as follows：

1） pwd: /home/user1/sbin/

```
#./mysql.sh restart                           Fail        Prompt:No such file or directory
#/home/user1/sbin/mysql.sh restart            ok
#../sbin/mysql.sh restart                     ok
```

2)  pwd: /home/user1

```
#./sbin/mysql.sh restart                      Fail　　     Prompt:No such file or directory
```

3） pwd: /

```
#/home/user1/sbin/mysql.sh restart　　        ok
```

> With any path, mysql.sh could run successfully with parameter 'start' and 'stop'.

So I guess this might be the bug in the script (mysql.sh). This script is similar to the official `mysql.sh` (mysql.server script), but with some modification.

So what's wrong with it?

Comment: `../sbin/mysql.sh restart` works? Sounds like a typo maybe or a bug in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: The line stating that `/home/user1/sbin restart` works implies that the script _is_ `/home/user1/sbin` and not `/home/user1/sbin/mysql.sh`.  You can't execute a directory (a directory's `x` permissions gives you permission to use the files in the directory).  I assume that's actually a typo in the question (you missed the `mysql.sh` from the end).

Comment: Do the `#` marks indicate that you're running the script as user `root`?  How many symbolic links are there in the path `/home/user1/sbin/mysql.sh` (inspect with `ls -l / /home /home/user1 /home/user1/sbin /home/user1/sbin/mysql.sh`)?  Are there any unusual permissions involved — the same `ls -l` command will reveal that?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,yeah,you are right,I missed mysql.sh at the end. And it's now modified.

Comment: running as user root; file permission is 777.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a space between the dot and slash like `#. /mysql.sh`? Why do you use the "./" at all? It is not required. The same is for directory `/home/user1`. Try invoking your script with only `sbin/mysql.sh restart`. Does filename completion work when you type your command?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "sh ./mysql.sh"

Be sure you have shebang at the first line in the script.

Comment: If you use `sh ./mysql.sh`, the shebang line is immaterial.  The shebang line only matters if you run the script directly, such as `mysql.sh` or `./mysql.sh`.

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't help.